# Criar apenas um e não varios modals

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, materialize

Bom galera tenho um sistema de cadastro e na parte de atualizar os dados de usuário ele me gera uma modal, porém a pagina está ficando pesada por haver muitos registros e cada registro possuir um modal, como faço para criar apenas um e popular o mesmo de acordo com cada registro?

Comment: Seria ótimo se você fizer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), melhor ainda se você acessar a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/) na sessão [Perguntando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) e ler [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente abra o modal através de uma função e passe como parâmetro um objeto ou array a ser exibido nesse modal. Dessa forma você passará a utilizar apenas um modal e o desempenho desejado será atingido.

Isto já deve ser suficiente, mas caso você poste algum código, irei editar esta solução de forma a aplicá-la ao seu código.